# UPS Magento 2.3.3

Tags: ups, shipping-label

`Magento 2.3.3` **UPS Shipping** Module Default that is available with `Magneto 2.3.3` 
we are able to get the Shipping Rates 
keys using 
UPS Type “united parcel service xml”
Gateway XML URL : https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate
Access License Number : Supplied by UPS
User ID: My USER ID
Origin of the Shipment: shipments Originating in other Countries   As India is not listed in the option 
Password Password 
Destination Type: resident
Tracking XML URL : https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track

with above we are able to get the shipping Rates

But when we create shipping label 
it give error

Failed to send items

even after entering all the fields

Kindly help

Comment: Are you able to find these solutions if yes then please let me know